# how to set matplotlib figsize using axes and subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Hello I have a very basic plot with matplotlib but I want to be able to set the figure size I am confused about how to do this when not using multiple subplots. I am confused about the relationship between the figsize and subplots see code below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))    

y = np.arange(1,6,1)
y1 = y**2
y2 = y**3
y3 = y**4
x = np.arange(1,101,20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y1)
ax.plot(x,y2)
ax.plot(x,y3)
```

Comment: You need to *either* use `plt.figure` *or* `plt.subplots`, not both, because they would both create a new figure.

Comment: put the figsize argument in the plt.subplots() call

Comment: fig, ax = plt.figure() this gives me an error of TypeError: 'Figure' object is not 
    iterable

Comment: okay I see what you meant: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10)) @muave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in 1 row and 1 column of subplots and that will give you one plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8,8))

y = np.arange(1,6,1)
y1 = y**2
y2 = y**3
y3 = y**4
x = np.arange(1,101,20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y1)
ax.plot(x,y2)
ax.plot(x,y3)

fig.savefig('eightbyeight.png', dpi = 300)
```